# Avoid strip specific attributes with TinyMce

Tags: tinymce, prestashop

I would like to add the following content

```
<label for="tab1">Product Name</label>
```

inside a long product description in Prestashop, but when I save the product the "for" attributes is stripped away from HTML code.

I did some research and I found that the editor is TinyMCE and so I tried to change the configuration by adding:

```
extended_valid_elements : "+@[class|name|id|for]",
```

inside TinyMCE init script but the result is the same. I am sure that I didn't use the cached version of old script because I disable the Chrome cache and checked that the javascript code was correct.

Do you have any idea?

Here it is the full configuration script:

```
default_config = {
        selector: ".rte" ,
        plugins : "colorpicker link image paste pagebreak table contextmenu filemanager table code media autoresize textcolor anchor",
        browser_spellcheck : true,
        toolbar1 : "code,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,alignfull,formatselect,|,blockquote,colorpicker,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,link,unlink,|,anchor,|,media,image",
        toolbar2: "",
        external_filemanager_path: ad+"/filemanager/",
        filemanager_title: "File manager" ,
        external_plugins: { "filemanager" : ad+"/filemanager/plugin.min.js"},
        language: iso,
        skin: "prestashop",
        statusbar: false,
        relative_urls : false,
        convert_urls: false,
        entity_encoding: "raw",
        extended_valid_elements : "+@[class|name|id|for]",
        valid_children : "+*[*]",
        valid_elements:"*[*]",
        menu: {
            edit: {title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste | selectall'},
            insert: {title: 'Insert', items: 'media image link | pagebreak'},
            view: {title: 'View', items: 'visualaid'},
            format: {title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'},
            table: {title: 'Table', items: 'inserttable tableprops deletetable | cell row column'},
            tools: {title: 'Tools', items: 'code'}
        }
    };
```

Comment: Which version of prestashop are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Have you tried to add to `extended_valid_elements` the tag and not the attribute? Like this:</s>

```
extended_valid_elements : "label[for]"
```

It's a fault of HTMLPurifier library, if you have control of the content of the html disable from the backoffice.
`Preferences -> General` set to NO `Use HTMLPurifier Library`

If you don't want to disable the library, you have to edit in `PrestaShop/tools/htmlpurifier/`

Maybe it's more easy to override the `purifyHTML()` method of `Tools` class, and add the 'for' attribute for the label, adding this when instancing the library:

```
$config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', 'label.for');
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention it, also with that setting is not working.

Comment: Sorry, It's not tinymce fault, but of HTMLPurifier library

Comment: At the end I disabled the HTML purifier library because it change also other HTML parts that I don't like. Thanks you very much!